# How to prevent Windows Security Warning about cookies when using WebClient?

Tags: c#, .net, webclient

When I go to some links, this window is displayed. How to disable it?

[image: Windows Security Warning]

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not", please try to find a more meaningful title for your question! And please to find a more meaningful title for your question!

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair the use of `WebClient` in the title seems subtle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your IE security and/or privacy settings are very strict.

Most web sites attempt to install a cookie onto your hard drive when you visit them, but if your security settings are too strict then the browser (IE specifically) will warn you before allowing this to happen.

Check out the Internet Explorer setting in Tools > Internet Options > [Security/Privacy tabs] and adjust them accordingly.

Note that this being a security-oriented *feature* there is nothing you can do AFAIK to circumvent this (otherwise, malicious websites would take over the internet...). Be also aware that if a Domain is involved, policies might be enforced which not allow security settings to be relaxed.